# How to display data from store in Ext.Component ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6-modern

I have store which return data from server:

```
Ext.define('Admin.store.dashboard.NPS', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.nps',

autoLoad : false,
proxy    : {
    type: 'api',
    url : SITE_URL + '/api/surveys/nps'
},
fields   : [
    {
        type: 'float',
        name: 'nps'
    }
]    
});
```

And I want to display that data in tpl of Ext.Component:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.dashboard.NPSPercent', {
extend: 'Ext.Component',
xtype: 'nps-percent',
bind: {
    data: {
        nps_percent: '{nps}'
    }
},

tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="percent">+{nps_percent.nps}</div>')
});
```

I tried bind data to loaded store but it dose not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates in components expect regular things like arrays, not stores. To render a template using a store as the datasource, use [Ext.view.View](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.view.View.html) class instead of just a component.

Comment: I have viewModel in my parent view where included my component.
So it means that all child element have access to viewModel parent view.

Comment: Not something I'd recommend (in projects of decent size at least). If you need data from parent component's vm, it's usually better to define a config in the child, and get that config bound to vm inside the parent.